# Convert JSON to a Array with struct

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I am trying to make a IOS app that is a home automation thing. I am using TableViewCell to display information.

My problem is that I have no idea how to get JSON to an Array with struct because I have to have struct I think.

My JSON is:

```
[{"namea":"TV","statea":"up_tv"},{"namea":"test","statea":"test"}]
```

My code is:

```
struct cellData {
let nameLabel : String!
let stateLabel : String!
}

class Main: UITableViewController {

var array = [cellData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    array = [cellData(nameLabel: "tv", stateLabel: "up_tv"),
             cellData(nameLabel: "tv", stateLabel: "down_tv")]

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return array.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = array[indexPath.row].nameLabel
    cell.stateLabal.text = array[indexPath.row].stateLabel
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I use `HandyJSON`. Just pod it and it will make your life way easier

Comment: How do I use HandyJSON

Comment: Read the .md on their github page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need jsonDecoder

```
struct cellData : Decodable {
   let nameLabel : String
   let stateLabel : String

      enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case nameLabel = "namea"
        case stateLabel = "statea"

      }
}
```

//

```
let str = """

    [{"namea":"TV","statea":"up_tv"},{"namea":"test","statea":"test"}]

"""

do {
       let cellArr = try JSONDecoder().decode([cellData].self, from: str.data(using:.utf8)!)
       print(cellArr)   //// check this 

} catch {

}
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
  let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id") as TableViewCell

}
```

Comment: No, This didn't work I got no errors but no tables cells appear

Comment: printed the array ??

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: check print statement in code if printed then you have problems in your table setup

Comment: No didn't get anything

Comment: can you attach the whole code you tried ?? Did you changes the struct as in answer ??

Comment: change the struct as in answer

Comment: I have know gotten this "[Dashboard.cellData(nameLabel: "TV", stateLabel: "up_tv"), Dashboard.cellData(nameLabel: "test", stateLabel: "test")]
"

Comment: from the print thing

Comment: I just need to remove the Dashboard. thing but how do I do that

Comment: It dispays as areference to the appName.structName , it's not actually inside the array , i added codingKeys to the struct if you want to get back your old names

Comment: reload the table after  let cellArr line

Comment: How do you do that? If you haven't noticed I have almost never coded in swift

Comment: write **self.tableView.reloadData()**

Comment: set identifier for your cell and load it as in edited answer